# Kernel panic caused when flashing images to an imx6 board

Tags: kernel, yocto, imx6

I'm using an imx6sll board with yocto bsp, and mfg tool to flash images.

The kernel and u-boot seem to flash without any issue but on flashing rootfs I get an error saying:

```
Writing inode tables: Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b

---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b
```

The ucl script which is used for flashing had run upto this command

```
UTP: received command '$ mkfs.ext3 -F -E nodiscard /dev/mmcblk1p2'
```

I can't seem to figure out what caused the panic. I ran ddr callibration test and it passed. Does anyone have any idea why this may be?

Comment: What is you kernel command line argument? Where does you root filesystem live?

Comment: this is my kernel command line: mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rootwait rw
my rootfile system is to be flashed to mmcblk1p2 if that's what the second part of your question means

Comment: You should be using `root=/dev/mmcblk1p2`

Comment: That's what I've been using all along :-/